# Regex, backreferences and alternations

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++, backreference

I'm trying to modify some texts using regex. This is the original text:

```
  <text xml:lang="en">"Insert Swab to Start Analysis"</text>
  <text xml:lang="es"></text>
  <text xml:lang="fr"></text>
  <text xml:lang="de"></text>
  <text xml:lang="pt"></text>
  <text xml:lang="du"></text>
```

And this is the desired text:

```
  <en>"Insert Swab to Start Analysis"</en>
  <es>"Insert Swab to Start Analysis"</es>
  <fr>"Insert Swab to Start Analysis"</fr>
  <de>"Insert Swab to Start Analysis"</de>
  <pt>"Insert Swab to Start Analysis"</pt>
  <du>"Insert Swab to Start Analysis"</du>
```

As you can see there have been two changes: modify the tags and copy the source text into the target languages.

I managed to do this using two different regex.

First regex (copy source text into target languages):

```
Search: (<text xml:lang=)"en">(.+?)(</text>)\r\n  \1"es">\3\r\n  \1"fr">\3\r\n  \1"de">\3\r\n  \1"pt">\3\r\n  \1"du">\3
Replace: \1"en">\2\3\r\n  \1"es">\2\3\r\n  \1"fr">\2\3\r\n  \1"de">\2\3\r\n  \1"pt">\2\3\r\n  \1"du">\2\3
```

Second regex (change tags):

```
Search: <text xml:lang="(en|es|fr|de|pt|du)">(.*?)(</[^>]*>)
Replace: <\1\>\2</\1>
```

I'm quite happy with the result but I'm wondering if all this can be done using a single regex and not two. The second regex I used is quite elegant but it does not copy the source text into the different target languages. I suspect it needs a little trick to work properly. Suggestions?

PD: I'm just using Notepad++ to do all this.

PD: It's a big XML file with many entries, not only the one I'm showing you here.

Comment: If your first regex works for you (note it is a very fragile approach), you may amend it to do the whole job. Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/9ZVBrR/1).

Comment: Yes it works well, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if the string is *always* formatted the same way, you may just amend the first regex to do the whole job for you:

**Find What**: `(<text xml:lang=")en">(.+?)(</text>)\R  \1es">\3\R  \1fr">\3\R  \1de">\3\R  \1pt">\3\R  \1du">\3`
**Replace With**: `<en>\2</en>\r\n  <es>\2</es>\r\n  <fr>\2</fr>\r\n  <de>\2</de>\r\n  <pt>\2</pt>\r\n  <du>\2</du>`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ZVBrR/1)

**Details**

- `(<text xml:lang=")` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1`): literal text `<text xml:lang="`
- `en">` - literal text `en">`
- `(.+?)` - Group 2: any 1 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(</text>)` - Group 3: literal text `</text>`
- `\R` - any line break sequence
- - two spaces
- `\1` - the text captured in Group 1
- `es">` - literal text `es">`
- `\3` - the text captured in Group 3
- `\R  \1fr">\3\R  \1de">\3\R  \1pt">\3\R  \1du">\3` - this is already clear from the above description.